# How to retrieve error message in StringTemplate?

Tags: java, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

How can I retrieve a compile time error message from StringTemplate as a String?

This code for instance:

```
STGroup stg = new STGroup('<', '>');
CompiledST compiledTemplate = stg.defineTemplate("receipt", "<an invalid template<>");
if (compiledTemplate == null)
    System.out.println("Template is invalid");
```

Will simply log something like "invalid came as a complete surprise to me", but I want to display this error message in my UI.

I can access the `ErrorManager` with `stg.errMgr`. I expected a method like `getErrors()` here, but there isn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set an error listener for the group, which would allow you to catch the error, and then pass it to the UI from there.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23507124/3380056) tells you more about implementing an STErrorListener. The example they give doesn't compile since they're throwing checked exceptions from within the ErrorListener. Perhaps a better approach would be to handle the errors directly inside the listener, or you could just throw a RuntimeException so you could catch the errors when you call `stg.defineTemplate(...)`.

```
public class MySTErrorListener implements STErrorListener {
...
@Override
public void compileTimeError(STMessage msg) {
    // do something useful here, or throw new RuntimeException(msg.toString())
}
...
}
```

If you were to throw the RuntimeException you could then catch it when you define the ST:

```
stg.setListener(new MySTErrorListener());
try{
    CompiledST compiledTemplate = stg.defineTemplate("receipt", "<an invalid template<>");
} catch (Exception e)
{
    // tell the UI about the error
}
```

Comment: Thx this works. I still think they have a weird default implementation of the error listener (just swallowing the exceptions), but fortunately you can indeed simply override it like this.